# What is the maximum rest client connection supported by Quarkus Rest server by default

Tags: quarkus

We have a Quarkus Rest service, and the client is using org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager with following settings

```
connMgr.setMaxTotal(20);
connMgr.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(6);
```

How would from service we can check if the service support maximum 20 connections?

By default what is the maximum connection allowed in quarkus?

Comment: Are you asking if the quarkus http server support 20 concurrent conection by default, or something different ?

Comment: I read it like this in one of the post -" The client to have 150 connections to a single host. But keep in mind, that server may not allow so many connections from a single client, that depends on the server configuration. " so what is that configuration for quarkus?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know quarkus is not limited you can configure a limit with this [property](https://quarkus.io/guides/http-reference#quarkus-vertx-http-config-group-server-limits-config_quarkus.http.limits.max-connections) but I would not suggest going over 100 connections never, because then you might run into the memory limits or cpu limits. This is why you replicate or scale your backends, so instead of having one jvm handling 150 connections, you have three smaller jvms handling 50 connections each one so you gain some high availability and fault tolerance.

If you want to test the behaviour in concurrency of your application you can always run a load test with Jmeter or other tools which will allow to simulate the load that you want and you would be able then to check the response time of your backend or if you run into resource bottlenecks or other issues.

Comment: I see we can limit the max number of concurrent connections by setting this property quarkus.http.limits.max-connections , It also says if this is set it is recommended to set a short idle timeout , how does this behave and what is the property to set the idle timeout .